# Indra's name as Shatakratu

Tags: puranas, indra, yajna

Devendra got the seat of heaven only after performing 100 Yajnas. So, he is known as Shatakratu. What was he before and any details of the Yajnas he performed is available in Purana ?

Comment: I think, the details such as where exactly was he, what was his name, if he was a king, which kingdom, who assisted him in yagas, I think, such details are not available in any Purana. It is only mentioned that he had performed 100 yagas and obtained the coveted throne of Swarga

Comment: Yes , but the duplicate question is covering all the details of  how he became Indra. Another answers also can be given  covering everything under previous question.

Answer (score 4):

This question is not a duplicate as the epithet *śatakratu* itself has a separate developmental history and the answer to the general question elsewhere is somewhat naive and incomplete by providing only the much later meaning attached to that epithet.

Indra's epithet as *śatakratu* occurs originally in the Rig Veda dozens of times, [most of the times as an invocative *śatakrato*](http://titus.fkidg1.uni-frankfurt.de/database/titusinx/titusinx.asp?LXLANG=21011&LXWORD=5B01atakrato&LCPL=0&TCPL=0&C=H&PF=24) and  did not mean "One who performed One Hundred Sacrifices" but "One with a Hundredfold insight or power".

Sāyaṇa (14th century) [glosses](https://archive.org/details/RgVedaWithSayanasCommentaryPart1/page/n87)  *śatakrato* as "*bahukarmayuktendra*" = "Oh Indra, You who are skillful in manifold deeds".

Monier-Williams dictionary gives: "having hundred-fold insight or power or a hundred counsels etc."

Of the [46 occurrences of *śatakrato*](http://titus.fkidg1.uni-frankfurt.de/database/titusinx/titusinx.asp?LXLANG=21011&LXWORD=5B01atakrato&LCPL=0&TCPL=0&C=H&PF=24), here are some:

> RV 1.4.8: *asyá pītvā́ śatakrato gʰanó vr̥trā́ṇām abʰavaḥ*
>
> RV VI.41.5: *śátakrato mādáyasvā sutéṣu prā́smā́m̐ ava pŕ̥tanāsu prá vikṣú*

It was only during the much later epic period that it was reinterpreted as meaning "One who performed One Hundred Sacrifices".